# IntelliJ ultimate autoselecting text problem

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-14, datagrip

I have a really weird problem with IntelliJ Idea Ultimate. It looks like it's holding a left mouse click by itself. So, if I move my cursor one line down it's selecting the entire line. The problem is that right click doesn't work anymore and I'm 99.99% sure it's not caused by column selection mode.
The editor is pretty much unusable right now.
This issue occurs in multiple IntelliJ editors (e.g. DataGrip, PyCharm)

Comment: Using **Column Select Mode** is kind of a workaround, but I'm looking for a real solution.

Comment: What's your IDE, JDK, OS?

Comment: IntelliJ Idea Ultimate, Oracle Java 8 version 201, Ubuntu 18.04 x64

Comment: What is the version of IDEA in Help | About window?

Comment: Build #IU-183.5912.21

Comment: It's up to date.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea Utilmate 2018.3

Comment: Please file a bug on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue